# Put a tags round user highlighted text?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to get the user selected area of a textarea and then insert `<a>` tags round it.

I use this to get the user selected area:

```
var textComponent = document.getElementById('article');
var selectedText;

if (document.selection != undefined)
{
    textComponent.focus();
    var sel = document.selection.createRange();
    selectedText = sel.text;
}

// Mozilla version
else if (textComponent.selectionStart != undefined)
{
    var startPos = textComponent.selectionStart;
    var endPos = textComponent.selectionEnd;
    selectedText = textComponent.value.substring(startPos, endPos)
}
```

Now, I know I can do a string search for the user selected text and insert a tags round it, but what happens if that user selected text appears twice in the text, for example.

> Hello to you, goodbye to you.

If the user highlights the second 'you' for the link they want, surely a string replace would put a tags around every instance of 'you'.

Whats the best way to do this?

Comment: I expect a string replace would give you the option of "replace all" or "replace first occurrence." If you use "first occurrence" and are able to start at the selection-start point, that might be sufficient?

Comment: keeping a `lastFocusedElement` variable may help. Find text in that particular element.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use my [jQuery plug-in](http://code.google.com/p/rangyinputs/) for this ([demo](http://rangyinputs.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/demos/textinputs_jquery.html)):

```
$("#article").surroundSelectedText('<a href="foo.html">', "</a>");
```

Alternatively you could use the [`getInputSelection()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/263743/how-to-get-caret-position-in-textarea/3373056#3373056) function that I've posted on Stack Overflow a few times to get the selection start and end character indices in all major browsers and then do string substitution on the textarea's `value`:

```
var sel = getInputSelection(textComponent);
var val = textComponent.value;
textComponent.value = val.slice(0, sel.start) +
                      '<a href="foo.html">' +
                      val.slice(sel.start, sel.end) +
                      "</a>" +
                      val.slice(sel.end);
```

Comment: is this the last version that needs to be included (+1 anyway)? https://code.google.com/p/rangyinputs/downloads/detail?name=textinputs_jquery.js&can=2&q=

Comment: @llnk: Yes. There's a copy on GitHub for the sake of jQuery's plugin site but I haven't needed to update it.

Comment: I am testing it and it's working pretty well. But I believe it lacks a a feature: When you add the tags a second time it doesn't remove the previous added tag.. It inserts two times those tag. Would it possible to add this behaviour when you use it two times with the same tags?

Comment: @llnk: This would be unnecessary clutter in the plugin. Once you have the character offsets of the selection then it's a matter of reasonably simple string manipulation to check for the existence of the tags before adding new tags.

Answer (score 2):

Why capture the selected text at all?  What you really want is the start/end positions to drop in tags.

```
var textComponent = document.getElementById('article');
var selectedText;
var startPos;
var endPos;

// the easy way
if (textComponent.selectionStart != undefined)
{
    startPos = textComponent.selectionStart;
    endPos = textComponent.selectionEnd;
}
// the hard way
else if (document.selection != undefined)
{
    textComponent.focus();
    var sel = document.selection.createRange();
    var range = document.selection.createRange();
    var stored_range = range.duplicate();
    stored_range.moveToElementText(textComponent);
    stored_range.setEndPoint( 'EndToEnd', range );
    startPos = stored_range.text.length - range.text.length;
    endPos = startPos + range.text.length;
} 

// add in tags at startPos and endPos
var val = textComponent.value;
textComponent.value = val.substring(0, startPos) + "<a>" + val.substring(startPos, endPos) + "</a>" + val.substring(endPos);
```

IE code modified from [this reference](http://the-stickman.com/web-development/javascript/finding-selection-cursor-position-in-a-textarea-in-internet-explorer/).

**EDIT:** Note Tim Down's comment about newlines.  Also, probably use his soltion, because it's better.

Comment: I would favour `selectionStart` and `selectionEnd` over the TextRange approach in browsers that support both (such as IE >= 9). Also, this code will not correctly detect selections beginning or ending with empty lines in IE: see http://jsfiddle.net/Lq5aP/1/. Finally, there's a typo in the IE branch: should be `endPos = startPos + range.text.length;`.

Comment: Fixed the code and recommended your solution, since this is a domain where you've obviously put in a lot of previous thought.