# Add <b></b> tags to selected text in a textarea

Tags: javascript, html

How  to create some javascript to do the following - when the user clicks the "BOLD" button, the selected text gets a "<b> " and a " </b>" wrapped around it.

```
 <form name="my">
<textarea name="textarea"></textarea><br />
<input type="button" value="bold" onclick="formatText ('b');" />
<input type="button" value="italic" onclick="formatText ('i');" />
<input type="button" value="underline" onclick="formatText ('u');" />
</form>
```

please help me to create java-script for supporting almost web browser

Comment: Why don't you use a pre-made [rich text editor](http://www.webdesignerdepot.com/2008/12/20-excellent-free-rich-text-editors/)?

Comment: Why reinvent the wheel?  Google "php javascript rich text editor" and take your pick

Comment: @egasimus, that's the idea. But that source is too old

Comment: @egasimus Sir ,I was try to allow some html tag only

Comment: @user: This is a highly non-trivial task. You should really take one of the existing solutions and adapt them to your needs, rather than rolling a complete solution on your own.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4897154/insert-tags-around-selected-text

Comment: "Too old"? I didn't bother checking all of them, but TinyMCE (#1 in egasimus's list) had a new release 2 days ago, CKEditor (#2) last April and NicEdit (#3) two weeks ago.

Comment: @Stecman  That won't work in IE

Comment: http://www.devguru.com/features/tutorials/wysiwyg/wysiwyg4.html  how can develop from this

Answer (score 1):

You should use an existing rich text editor, they are configurable so you can give users only the features what you want them to use. They also have the added benefit of working across a range of different browsers.

An example of setting up [tinyMCE](http://www.tinymce.com/) with only Bold, Italic and Underline.

```
tinyMCE.init({
    // General options
    mode : "textareas",
    theme : "advanced",

    // Theme options
    theme_advanced_buttons1 : "bold,italic,underline"
});
```

Comment: I did not know that TinyMCE offered a lightweight version of their script & that they would be this customizable. I have searched for hours and have tried to create one myself, I am so grateful to have found this tip!

Answer (score 0):

Please try script given below...

```
<script>
 function formatText (key){

    var elem = document.my.textarea; 
    /*start of selection area*/ 
    var start = elem.selectionStart;
    var end = elem.selectionEnd;
    var len = elem.value.length;
    var sel_txt = elem.value.substring(start,end);

    if (sel_txt != ""){
      var begin_tag = "<"+key+">"; 
      var close_tag =  "</"+key+">";
      var replace = begin_tag + sel_txt + close_tag;
      elem.value = elem.value.substring(0,start) + replace + elem.value.substring(end,len);
   }
</script>
```

I have tried script on http://jsfiddle.net/VRqU3/. Please check it.

I hope it will be work for you,
thank you,

Answer (score 0):

This would be relatively simple were it not for IE < 9, which does not support `selectionStart` and `selectionEnd` properties of textarea elements. Here's a previous answer of mine detailing how to do this:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/10739034/96100

Answer (score -1):

Try this function:

```
function formatText(tag) {
   var Field = document.getElementById('text');
   var val = Field.value;
   var selected_txt = val.substring(Field.selectionStart, Field.selectionEnd);
   var before_txt = val.substring(0, Field.selectionStart);
   var after_txt = val.substring(Field.selectionEnd, val.length);
   Field.value = before_txt + '<' + tag + '>' + selected_txt + '</' + tag + '>' + after_txt;
}
```

Example: http://jsbin.com/ilecug/
Source: http://jsbin.com/ilecug/edit